# I need to add multiple activities on one button

Tags: android, button, location

I need a button to open two activities on one page. For example when I click on the button it must display the time and the location on the same page, but the time and location activities are in separate activities. Could anyone help please?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You cant have more than 1 activity at the same page - the page itself is the activity , you can use fragments insted

Comment: yeah kind of figured,so i combined my two activities into one,it worked but then my button stopped working

Comment: Post your code and i will help you

Comment: its cool ive given up on that and found a roundabout method

Answer (score 0):

You have to use fragments for that. Learn more from here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments